# Inverse proportion

Tags: arithmetic

I am not sure how to approach this question, can I get some help? 
This is an inverse proportion question.

$y$ is inversely proportional to the square of $x$.

Find the percentage change of $x$ when $y$ is decreased by $36\%$ .

Not sure where to continue after my working:

Old $y$ value = $1 y$

New $y$ value = $0.64 y$

$$y = \frac{k}{x^2}\tag{1}$$

$$0.64y = \frac{k}{x^2}\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the initial value of $x$ be $x_1$ and the value after the change in $y$ be $x_2$. Continuing from where you left off,
$$y=\frac{k}{{x_1}^2}\tag1$$
$$0.64y=\frac{k}{{x_2}^2}\tag2$$
Dividing $(2)$ by $(1)$,
$$0.64=\frac{{x_1}^2}{{x_2}^2}$$
$$0.8=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$$
$$x_1=0.8x_2$$
or
$$x_2=1.25x_1$$

Thus, the value of $x$ increases by $25\%$

Comment: Hey , shouldn't it be X2 ^2 / X1^1 ? Because it's 2 divide by 1

Comment: @user307640 Since it is $(2)$ divided by $(1)$, the ${x_2}^2$ term which is in the denominator in $(2)$ stays in the denominator.